# Verbose output of ./configure not verbose at all

Tags: configure

I have a problem installing OpenOCD:

```
checking for ftd2xx.h... yes
checking for library containing FT_GetLibraryVersion... no
```

Said library is installed and tested.

In hopes of seeing where is `configure` looking for the library, I passed the `verbose` command switch. No change at all!

Is there a way to check where and under what name is configure looking for said library?

Comment: Did you read the last few lines?

Comment: how exactly did you "pass the verbose command switch"?

Comment: `./configure --verbose --enable-ftdi --enable-ft2232_ftd2xx`. I found my mistake elsewhere, but this `config.log` is good to know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`./configure` usually creates a `config.log` file. It should contain the commands executed to check for the library.

Answer (score 4):

As @Matteo said, there is `config.log`.

Notice, it is not always created in the same directory as your `configure` script you ran. See the configure output to find the log -- it will be in the last few lines.

If you want to see what your configure script does, open the `configure` script and add `set -x` in the second line (after `#!/bin/bash` or something similar).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

... # rest of the configure script
```

The output would be pretty verbose, but you would have information about each command script ran.

Comment: Or just `bash -x ./configure...`

Comment: On systems where `sh` is `bash`, you can also do `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace ./configure` for all `sh` and `bash` invocations to have `xtrace` enabled.

Comment: good point @StéphaneChazelas, thanks! :) I would check maybe, but wouldn't it affect the environment of the script run somehow? Thanks for your info share

Answer (score 1):

The configure file, is a shell script and cannot have verbose logging by default, unless someone wrote specific echo instructions in it. But you should find something like configure.ac / configure.in which will have details on what logic is ran to assert the presence/absence of a particular program / library. I guess that should be more than enough for you to debug the issue in case configure.log doesn't have any information in it.